# Templates for moderators for comments

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comments

So I'm not sure if this idea has come up, but on Travel.SE we have very regular comments to new users, generally along the lines of :

"Welcome to Travel.SE.  Currently your question is not a great fit...."

"Welcome to Travel.SE.  You've asked a question as an answer, and as such..."

"Welcome to Travel.SE. You may not have seen our [faq]...."

and so on.

I can now type "Welcome to Travel.SE" nearly as fast as I type my name, and was wondering if there might be room or feasibility for custom templates for this...

Something like "Mod Menu"->Add Comment Template->"insert custom text"

Just a thought, not sure what others do about this or whether anyone else does tend to welcome new users,  but I thought I'd see what people say.

Comment: Would this fit your needs: [AutoReviewComments - Pro-forma comments for SE](http://stackapps.com/q/2116)?

Comment: We [do this](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/190/welcoming-new-users) on Mi Yodeya assisted by a template and cut/paste.  A little more automation would be handy (but it should allow further editing, e.g. to say something about the post).

Comment: The Pro-forma comment script is pretty useful, though I miss it when moderating from my tablet where I can't install user scripts. So there would still be some advantage to integrate it into SE.

Comment: I was thinking about this only yesterday. Great idea.